# Variable does not change its value

Tags: php

I have been trying to analyze it for like hours now but I can't understand what was wrong with my code :(

```
$d = 1; //I declare this variable as 1
$a = 0;
while($d<$arraycount-2){
  while ($a < 40){
    $c = 0;
    $b = 0;

    while($c < $fc){
      $finaloutput = $finaloutput.$database_returned_data[$d][$c].","; //But here, in this loop $d is always 1

      $c++;
    }

    while($b < 5){
      $finaloutput = $finaloutput.$mydata[$a][$b].",";
      $b++;
    }

    $finaloutput = $finaloutput."--END--";
    $a++;
  }
  $d++; //But it increments successfully. Hence, the while loop terminates after it meets the criteria.
}
```

The variable $d is always 1 inside the other loop but it increments outside the loop. Note there is a while statement inside the while. Is there anything wrong?

I'm using `$d` for my array:

```
 $finaloutput = $finaloutput.$database_returned_data[$d][$c].",";
```

I am a noob poster. Feel free to ask for more details :)

Comment: What is the value of $arrayCount?  and what is the value of $fc?

Comment: you don't increment `$d` in the scope of that `while`....?  what is `$arraycount-2`?

Comment: missing $a reset after inner loop, `$a=0` between to while

Comment: What is `$fc` supposed to be?

Comment: The value of $arraycount is the size of the $database_returned_data

Comment: @cske yes i don't reset $a intentionally

Comment: if you're deliberately not resetting $a then what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @SiKni8 $fc is a variable where I get the number of fields that should be included in my final output. This one is not a problem though, because I get my expected output using this code. it's just that the $database_returned_data stays on $database_returned_data[1][$c]

Comment: If you don't reset `$a` then inner loop with execute only one cycle, in which `$d` is set to 1.

Comment: Resetting $a solved it. Thank you. So sorry for being hard-headed :)

Comment: I think the issue is not about wether a variable is set or not. I think it's more about writing readable code. It's hard to tell what the code is supposed to do and why.

Comment: yes @bestprogrammerintheworld you are right. I was just not certain what variables I am going to use that is why I end up using letters which I understand very well if you'd ask me. Well because it's my code, but I think I should revise it before I post it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set `$a` here:

```
while($d<$arraycount-2){
    while ($a < 40){
```

So on every iteration besides the first this while condition won't run.

just change it to:

```
while($d<$arraycount-2){
    $a = 0;
    while ($a < 40){
```

Comment: my problem is that $database_returned_data[$d][$c] stays as $database_returned_data[1][$c]. $d does not increment inside that loop

Comment: the $a is for the $mydata array which doesn't have any problem anyway.